# How much outgoing data should I buffer in a Linux driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am creating a driver for a custom point-to-point communications device (think super serial port) and I'm wondering how I should handle the outgoing data. Specifically, how much data should I allow it to buffer?

Currently, I limit the buffer size passed into write() to a maximum of 16kb or 4 pages on my system.  I would imagine standard data would be significantly less than this.  My write function kmalloc()'s enough memory for the buffer and copies it into kernel space.  Using the built-in linked list, I queue up the data for a DMA transaction.  I map it using the dma_map_single() API.  The device itself doesn't have a large buffer, so it transmits data directly from the DMA'd buffer.  Then when the transmit is complete it raises an interrupt where I unmap and free it.

So back to my question, given that I am kmalloc()ing every time the user performs a write, should I limit the number of buffers that are put into the queue?  Or is there an inherent flaw in the strategy I've just described?

Edit to answer comments about the data source: Unfortunately I'm not writing the end user software so I don't know anything about the original data source.  I can say the outgoing data rate is not all that fast (256kbps max) and memory is very tight on this embedded system.

Comment: IMHO this can't be answered without more knowledge of the device and how it is used - in effect, which is the greatest issue: letting it run dry, blocking client program writes, or allowing the increasing latency of growing buffers to decouple programs from actual transmission time?

Comment: Need to know all the data sinks/sources in the chain and what their input and output required rates are. Then you can analyze what your buffering needds are. As Chris Stratton said: more information is needed in order to answer the question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to research the intended usage patterns of what you are working on.  Otherwise you'll design something that might be proper, but not particularly suitable for the way people end up trying to use it.

Comment: Chris, I would love to but unfortunately that's not really an option at the moment.  The thing I am getting from this conversation though is that the method I am using, while it may or may not be ideal for the use case, is not inherently flawed in some way.